# Enabling SPNEGO security in Angular

Tags: angular, security, angular7, spnego, web-application-security

How we can enable SPNEGO security in Angular 7 so that application will be secured?. I am having WebSphere version 8.5.

I want to enable SPNEGO in angular application so the it will be secured and hosted on WebSphere server. I am using WebSphere version 8.5 and Angular 7.